# Rewriting of the URL is prevented by an existing file in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

the rewriting of the URL is prevented by an existing file. I have a lot of HTML files that I want to call in with a folder in the URL. This is my approach so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^remote$ /remote.html
RewriteRule ^hardware$ /hardware.html
RewriteRule ^hardware/product-xy$ /product-xy.html
```

Unfortunately that does not work. If I choose a different "folder" name, because I don't call it up like here, it works:

```
RewriteRule ^remote$ /remote.html
RewriteRule ^hardware$ /hardware.html
RewriteRule ^foo/product-xy$ /product-xy.html
```

How can I solve this via htaccess? Can someone tell me what is colliding?

EDIT:

I remove this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Now it works.

Comment: Are you trying to access your `.html` files without using extension at the end ?

Comment: Yes, but nothing was done there.

Comment: Is it resolved now or are you still looking for a solution?